# Overly long review process (>2 years) without feedback

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors

We submitted a paper to a journal more than 2 years ago. After 1 year had passed without any news, I asked the editors for an update on the status of our paper, and they mentioned they were still waiting for referee reports. After the second year of waiting, I wrote another email about a status update, without getting any response from the editors. The long process is a real nuisance for all authors involved, in particular for the junior ones who need publications on their track record. This is why I would like to see a decision (positive or negative) soon, but on the other hand I would like to not offend the editors. What would you advise us to do in this situation?

Comment: What field? ,,,

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was a similar question that was given the following advice for no response from editors: contact the managing editor or call the journal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the time for being polite is past.

Ask them for a *realistic* projection about a decision. Perhaps even mention the impact of the delay on the careers of junior members.

There might be reasons for a long delay, but not for a long time between communications. Don't ask for an immediate decision unless you want to risk the inevitable rejection.

But it is their responsibility to choose reliable reviewers.

But if your paper is especially esoteric, making it hard to find suitable reviewers, then starting over will also lead to long delays. If that happens, keep a tighter rein on the process.